# Ubuntu: How do I make my built in microphone default again?

Tags: ubuntu, microphone

I connected an external microphone (mic), and now it's the default mic. I know it's the default mic because when I use Skype the external mic is the only one which works on the default sound input. The internal works only on HDA Intel (hw:intel,0) and its the only mic that Rosetta Stone is picking up which is the external one. All I need to know is how to make my built in one default again.

Answer (score 2):

Default devices in Ubuntu should be controlled from the Devices tab under System > Preferences > Sound.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are running Windows since you didn't specify.  Go into **Control Panel** and select **Sound**.  From there go to the **Recording** tab and select the microphone you want and use the *right mouse click* to specify it as the default.

If you are talking about the default in Skype then go to **Tools**, **Options**, **Audio Settings** (under *General*) and then select the audio source from the drop down next to *Microphone*.

If you are referring to another operating system or software then please update your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

under device in sound preferences there is> HDA intel(alsa mixer) and Realtek alc68(oss mixer)
and i dont think either of those are my mic devices.